# SELECT depending on previous columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do something, what with pseudo-code would be like

```
for each uniqeValue in column1
   for each uniqeValue in column2
       SELECT uniqueValueColumn1, uniqueValueColumn2, numberOfRepetitions
```

Is there a mechanism that would let me do this?

Edit:

As requested I provide more specific input and wanted output.

```
Name |BirthDate
-----------------
Chris|1999-01-01
Chris|1999-01-01
Chris|1999-12-12
Tom  |1999-12-12
```

Output:

```
Name |BirthDate |Repetitions
----------------------------
Chris|1999-01-01|          2
Chris|1999-12-12|          1
Tom  |1999-12-12|          1
```

I thought about GROUP BY, but didn't succeed in applying it.
My try for now is sth. like

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name,
    (SELECT DISTINCT BirthDate),
    (SELECT COUNT SELECT DISTINCT Name,
        (SELECT DISTINCT BirthDate))
    FROM Table
```

Of course it doesn't work because it doesn't have right to. My intention is to get know how to correctly implement this COUNT or how to replace it.

Comment: How about `GROUP BY` here?

Comment: Please provide a set of source data and your desired output.

Comment: This could be any number of things. CROSS JOIN seems to be the most likely but without any more details it is anybody's guess.

Comment: numberofrepetitions ??? Should that just be hardcoded to 1 since it is unique ? Your question is really cryptic

Comment: @t-clausen.dk it's number of records that were collapsed to one row while applying filter to unique assembly of Name and BirthDate columns.

Comment: Good grief...with your recent update this is pretty clear that all you need is to use basic aggregation. Seems that Jacob H answered this for you. Notice how clear it becomes when you provide sample data and desired output? That took this from an unanswerable question to one that is super simple to help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a query to `COUNT` the number of records where `[Name]` and `[Birthdate]` are the same. This should work for that purpose:

```
SELECT [Name], [BirthDate], COUNT(*) AS Repetitions
FROM Table
GROUP BY [Name], [BirthDate]
```

Comment: I was trying this but it failed because of my mistake (incorrectly used "CAST" inside). Thank you - it works now.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
select name, birthdate, count(*)
from person
group by name, birthdate
```

Check and test at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96898/1